# How to get the 24 hours date format in Fullcalendar with Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal, fullcalendar

I know the options of the official documentation.

All OTHER options than the `timeFormat` and the `axisFormat` works very well but my `timeFormat` is always displaying as am/pm where I need 24 hours format.

```
/**
 * @file    
 * Processes the FullCalendar options and passes them to the integration.
 */   
    (function ($) {
    Drupal.fullcalendar.plugins.fullcalendar = {
        options: function (fullcalendar) {
            var settings = Drupal.settings.fullcalendar[fullcalendar.dom_id];
            var options = {
                dragOpacity: 0.5,  /* This option IS working*/
                timeFormat: { '': 'H:mm' },   /* This is NOT working */
                axisFormat: { '': 'H:mm' },
                columnFormat: {
                    month: 'ddd',    // Mon
                    week: 'ddd d/M', // Mon 9/7
                    day: 'dddd d/M'  // Monday 9/7
                },
...
```

I'm using Drupal 7, module which embed Fullcalendar library (version 1.5.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `timeFormat`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/) the 24 hour format is denoted by `HH`. Try changing your code to this:

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.fullcalendar.plugins.fullcalendar = {
  options: function (fullcalendar) {
    var settings = Drupal.settings.fullcalendar[fullcalendar.dom_id];
    var options = {
    dragOpacity: 0.5,  /* This option IS working*/
timeFormat: { '': 'HH:mm' },   /* This is NOT working */
axisFormat: { '': 'HH:mm' },
    columnFormat: {
            month: 'ddd',    // Mon
            week: 'ddd d/M', // Mon 9/7
            day: 'dddd d/M'  // Monday 9/7
    },
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Drupal 7 module [Fullcalendar](https://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar) then you can set the time format in the configuration of the View.

Edit the View and check *Settings* in the *Format* section. Inn the *Time/date Settings* fieldset you can change the format.

Default is h:mm{ - h:mm}. Change this to HH:mm{ - HH:mm} for the 24 hour time notation.[image]